# How to interpolate uniformly distributed 3D data in a rotated coordinate system rapidly?

Tags: c++, matlab, interpolation, image-rotation

I have a 3D volume data on a rotated uniform grid.The grid **before** rotation satisfies all properties of `meshgrid/ndgrid` of matlab as explained [here](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/interpolating-gridded-data.html). i.e grid is uniformly spaced, no holes and grid vectors are monotonically increasing.  I want a 2D slice/sub volume of this data. If the grid is not rotated, I could use `interp3`/`griddedInterpolant` functions. But right now, I am forced to use [`scatteredInterpolant`](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant.html) which is horribly slow in 3D case. Is there a faster way to interpolate this kind of data without any axes transformation?. I would also appreciate if there are any `c++` libraries which can handle this. Thank you.

A minimal 2D MATLAB code for clarity. In this code, say I know **Xr,Yr,Vr,Xqr,Yqr** and I need **Vqr**.

```
%% generate uniorm @D grid and arb. gaussian as grid value 
[X,Y]=ndgrid(-1:1e-2:1);
V=reshape(mvnpdf(cat(2,X(:),Y(:)),0,[0.2 0.1;0.1 0.2]),size(X));
figure,subplot(221),surface(X,Y,reshape(V,size(X))),shading interp,title('unrotated grid')

% Now rotate the grid with some angle and get grid value
theta=deg2rad(20); %say you don't this
rotmat=[cos(theta) -sin(theta); sin(theta) cos(theta)];
XYr= rotmat*cat(2,X(:),Y(:))';
Xr=reshape(XYr(1,:),size(X));
Yr=reshape(XYr(2,:),size(X));
Vr=reshape(mvnpdf(XYr',0,[0.2 0.1;0.1 0.2]),size(Xr));
subplot(222),surface(Xr,Yr,Vr),shading interp,title('rotated grid')

%get some target points which has different orientaion
[Xq,Yq]=ndgrid(-0.5:0.1:1);
thetaq=deg2rad(-32);
rotmatq=[cos(thetaq) -sin(thetaq); sin(thetaq) cos(thetaq)];
XYqr= rotmatq*cat(2,Xq(:),Yq(:))';
Xqr=reshape(XYqr(1,:),size(Xq));
Yqr=reshape(XYqr(2,:),size(Xq));

% control
F=griddedInterpolant(X,Y,V);
subplot(223),surface(Xqr,Yqr,F(Xqr,Yqr)),shading interp,title('unrotated grid: interp2')

% works but slow
Fs=scatteredInterpolant(Xr(:),Yr(:),Vr(:));
subplot(224),surface(Xqr,Yqr,Fs(Xqr,Yqr)),shading interp,title('rotated grid: slow scattered interp')

%I need something faster here.
Fr=griddedInterpolant(Xr,Yr,Vr);  % error: Data is not valid NDGRID format
Vqr=Fr(Xr,Yr,Vr);  % error
```

Comment: If you're doing a lot of interpolations, why not just store the coordinates in the rotated frame, and keep track of the angles needed to get back to the real coordinates? It shouldn't be too hard to find the rotation angles.

It's also not too difficult to write up a custom interpolation function that works for your rotated but uniform grid. Without working through the details, I think you'd probably be redoing some operations if you're doing a lot of interpolations, which is why it might be better to just work in the rotated frame until final presentation (or whatever).

Comment: That's my last resort. It is possible to figure out the transformation from the center, inplane rotation angle and normal vector I have. But I am looking for a easy way out if there is any. Moreover, as far as I understand, `scatteredinterpolant` is slow because it is hard to establish the neighborhood of the points. In my case, the neighborhood is relatively easy to establish. So there has to be a middle way.